# Can't connect to server while other users can

Tags: connection

I am having a weird connection issue with a specific website and the owner of the webhost is all out of ideas to help me.

My problem is the following:
I can't connect to the website `www.duivelsei.nl`, any of its subdomains or the website of its webhost (which is most likely located on the same server). The connection times out. Other users don't have this problem, only this internet connection appears to have issues.

I have already tried the following things:

- Changing browsers (from Firefox to Chrome and Edge)
- Changing devices, my mobile phone connected to the same WiFi also times out.
- Emptied the browser's cache
- Restarted computer and router
- Did a malware scan
- Flushed DNS
- Disabled Firewall and Antivirus
- Checked `C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`, this file was empty.
- I tried accessing the server through both the domainname and the IP-adress directly
- `tracert www.duivelsei.nl` did bounce 10 times before timing out (so it's not my ISP)
- The IP adress displayed when performing `ping www.duivelsei.nl` matches the IP adress of the server, so it doesn't seem to be a DNS issue.
- My IP-adress is not explicitly blacklisted by the server.

I have no idea what is causing it. All I know is I was accessing the server through git and I remember mistyping my password a couple of times, but I would assume that if that was related, it would show up in some blacklist.

Tracert output:

---

```
E:\Users\Jarko>tracert www.duivelsei.nl

Tracing route to ghs.l.google.com [74.125.128.121]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1

  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  50729801.static.ziggozakelijk.nl [hidden just to be sure]

  3     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  D5225411.static.ziggozakelijk.nl [213.34.84.17]

  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  gv-rc0052-cr102-ae40-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.160.58]

  5     3 ms     2 ms     3 ms  asd-tr0610-cr101-ae58-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.22]

  6     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  72.14.222.56

  7     3 ms     4 ms     3 ms  108.170.241.195

  8     3 ms     3 ms     4 ms  66.249.94.167

  9     7 ms     6 ms     6 ms  108.170.237.124

 10     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  108.170.232.9

 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.

 12     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  74.125.128.121


Trace complete.
```

---

```
E:\Users\Jarko>tracert forum.duivelsei.nl

Tracing route to forum.duivelsei.nl [31.186.169.33]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1

  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  50729801.static.ziggozakelijk.nl [-]

  3     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  D5225411.static.ziggozakelijk.nl [213.34.84.17]

  4     5 ms     1 ms     1 ms  gv-rc0052-cr102-ae40-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.160.58]

  5     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  asd-tr0610-cr101-ae58-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.22]

  6     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  et-1-0-0.bb02.ams-01.leaseweb.net [80.249.209.215]

  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.

etc

 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Please [edit] and include the tracert output.

Comment: So, you're getting there, its not a routing issue.  Its proxy, explicit denial, firewall, or TCP Windowing.  If a trace works, a ping normally would to.. use the option in PING to try different packet sizes with the DF (don't fragment) set, to see what the max packet size would be.if you can get to,or above 1472 bytes (ethernet is 1500)  then TCP window_max may not be he issue. Good Luck.

Comment: Hmm, so apparently the main website `www.duivelsei.nl` is located on a different server as the subdomains, and my problem is actually connecting to those. I added the `tracert` output for those domains as well. (the main website works suddenly, but the subdomains still don't)

Comment: The webhost double checked and I am not explicitly IP-banned from the server. I am all out of ideas as to what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has had no feedback:

The problem has solved itself after a long time (~1 month). It appears that some system triggered on entering the wrong password too many times, effectively ip-banning me.

The way I found out about it is because another user has the same problem now.

I am still unsure about the source of the ip-ban, since neither the controlpanel on our domain nor the webhost could see any hint to this.